# Object reference exception when importing content in Episerver

Tags: import, export, runtime-error, episerver, optimizely

We are using Optimizely/Episerver CMS 11.20. When trying to export a page hierarchy from our production environment and then import the resulting ExportedFile.episerverdata file to our acceptance test environment I get the following error:

`[Importing content 70725_133679] Exception: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.`

I have no idea what 70725_133679 is referring to. Is there a way to look this up, e.g. via an SQL query against the "EPi" database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It refers to a specific version of some content (which could be just about anything).

You could try to browse to `https://yoursite/EPiServer/CMS/#context=epi.cms.contentdata:///70725_133679` (note the ID at the end) to see which content it is.

Comment: Thank you Ted! This seems like a nice way to find the content without having to look in the database. I just had to replace the question mark with a hash mark in  the URL:

https://<site>/EPiServer/CMS/#context=epi.cms.contentdata:///70725_133679

Comment: Ah, of course - my mistake. Edited.

Answer (score 0):

Got another answer on a Optimizely forum (thanks to Surjit Bharath):

The following SQL against the EPi database gives information about the referenced content:

```
select * from tblContent where pkID = 70725 
select * from tblWorkContent where pkID = 133679
```

This too points to a submit button. I have yet to understand why that block would cause an exception during import, but now I at least have a place to start digging.